# What exactly is argument of a function?

Tags: functions

I saw the meaning of argument in the context of mathematics in wikipedia, It said that 'In mathematics, an argument of a function is a value provided to obtain the function's result. It is also called an independent variable.' In the first line it said 'an argument is a value provided to obtain the function's result.' , if this is the definition of argument then the values we substitute for 'x' is supposed to be the argument not the 'x' itself. But then in the next sentence 'It is also called an independent variable.' it said the 'x' is the argument. As I advanced they said that the value we input in the place of 'x' is the argument value, this is line which says that 'A function of two or more variables is considered to have a domain consisting of ordered pairs or tuples of argument values.'. The definition they gave for argument doesn't seem to mean that 'x' is the argument, but instead the values we substitute for 'x' is the argument. I am confused. I need assistance. I apologize if the question I asked is not supposed to asked here, but in English Language learners stack exchange.

Comment: The terminology here isn't particularly settled simply because in the grand scheme of things it doesn't matter. Great mathematical results have not been obtained by dwelling into intricacies about what is the meaning of the word "argument". Having said that, the word "argument" is used in both meanings - as a name of the variable in the function definition (say, $x$) - where it may be also called "formal argument" - and also as a name for the actual value that $x$ may be substituted with (also called "input" of the function).

Comment: In programming, the difference is usually made more explicit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming) ("formal arguments" vs. "actual arguments").

Comment: When I’m defining a function $f$, I’ll say things like “if $x$ is a number then $f(x) = x^2$.” So $x$ is not a “variable” (whatever that would mean), it is just some particular number.

Comment: "f(x)" is an *expression* used to name a function; we use variables $x,y$ etc to specify how many argument-places the function has.

Comment: -littleO, I have trouble understanding your explanation.

Comment: A *function* is a "mechanism" (rule, etc) that for every "input" produces an "output". If the function is "numerical", the input will be a number from the specified domain of the function (natural, rational, real, complex,...) and so for the output value.

Comment: I have understood the meaning of argument. Thanks for looking out for me guys.

Comment: But we may have "non-numerical" functions: "father of x" will be a function that for every human as argument value will produce as output the corresponding father. Or we may have "mixed" functions like "length of x" that for every *expression in a specified language as argument value will produce as output a number (the number of symbols of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

I also checked this Wikipedia page to learn the argument of a function and had the same confusion. Thanks for the answers here. They helped me understand the argument of a function more.
Based on my understanding, the first two sentences on this Wikipedia page ("In mathematics, an argument of a function is a value provided to obtain the function's result. It is also called an independent variable.") may be rewritten as "In mathematics, an argument of a function can be a value provided to obtain the function's result. It can also be an independent variable." I think the rewriting would help the understanding of the context on the Wikipedia page.
The expressions "value provided to obtain the function's result" and "an independent variable" are not the intrinsic definition of the argument of a function, but descriptions of the roles of the argument of a function from two perspectives.
(I am a beginner. If there are any mistakes, please point them out and correct them. thx very much.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1912725)